# AdaFruit PiPlate(LCD+Keys) + PWM port + DS18B20 temp sensor

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, wiring, wiringpi

I would like to know if it is possible to use at the same time, the [Adafruit LCD+Keys](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1110) + the PWM port(to control a MOSFET) + one temperature sensor (DS18B20) and its oneWire protocol?

I was concerned about the GPIO poles. If yes, how?

I've the RpiV2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a Pi2 (40 pin expansion header).

The linked Adafruit LCD is I2C based so only uses two gpios (SDA/SCL).

That means you have a choice of four gpios for hardware PWM (gpios 12/13/18/19) and any spare gpio for the 1-wire bus (1-wire used to be limited to gpio 4, that is no longer the case).

Although there are four hardware PWM gpios there are only two hardware PWM channels (12/18 share one channel, 13/19 the other).

Comment: Nice :) I didn't know if it was only the LCD that was using the I2C, or if the keys were also using it, also I don't understand why it is using so much element(18 pin) when plugging it directly on the Pi.

Comment: @J4N I expect the full header is used partly for mechanical reasons to make the unit secure and partly because it is an evolution of an earlier design which used more gpios.

Comment: Well, I can't wait to get started on my small project